# Does the Autoplay feature automatically activate the Continue feature?

Tags: the-great-ace-attorney-chronicles

I lost once, while Autoplay was on, and unlike when I lost when Autoplay was off, there was no prompt asking me how I wanted to continue, instead, it seemed to restart the scene / segment automatically?

Is that really what happened, because of Autoplay?